# Authentication Failed while making REST API call to GET container details in AZURE STORAGE BLOB

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage, rest

I am trying to obtain Container details in Azure Storage Blob. But it throws Auth Failed, I think there might be problems with my resource string formulation.
Here's the code:

```
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
const request = require("request");
const parser = require("xml2json");

require("dotenv").config();

const account = process.env.ACCOUNT_NAME || "";
const key = process.env.ACCOUNT_KEY || "";

var strTime = new Date().toUTCString();
var strToSign =
  "GET\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-date:" +
  strTime +
  `\nx-ms-version:2018-03-28\n/${account}/demo?restype:container`;
var secret = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(key);
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(strToSign, secret);
var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
var auth = `SharedKey ${account}:${hashInBase64}`;

const options = {
  url: `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net/demo?restype=container`,

  headers: {
    Authorization: auth,
    "x-ms-date": strTime,
    "x-ms-version": "2018-03-28",
  },
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
  console.log(error);
  console.log(response.headers["Last-Modified"]);
  console.log(response);
}

request(options, callback);
```

In the above example `demo` is a private container in my account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try by changing the following line of code:

```
var strToSign =
  "GET\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-date:" +
  strTime +
  `\nx-ms-version:2018-03-28\n/${account}/demo?restype:container`;
```

to

```
var strToSign =
  "GET\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-date:" +
  strTime +
  `\nx-ms-version:2018-03-28\n/${account}/demo\nrestype:container`;
```